# How can I extract a key with different values?

Tags: javascript, json

I have several same keys and multiple values I just want to parse JSON with keys and values and extract **device_id**, As you can see all **device_id** is the same but the value of them is different.

> How can I parse.json and have just device_id: values?
> My file is like this :

```
[
    {
      "id": "c19ca393.e14b1",
      "type": "tab",
      "label": "Flow 1",
      "disabled": false,
      "info": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "a15871bb.7c3b2",
      "type": "input-distributer",
      "z": "c19ca393.e14b1",
      "name": "input-distributer",
      "device_id": "93e71ba7-fb56-5592-a5f6-d855203dd7ae",
      "device_name": "nmos-cpp_node_10-20-130-24:6131",
      "x": 280,
      "y": 260,
      "wires": [
        [
          "6548d2cb.45bc1c"
        ],
        [
          "7cf8bc7e.204a84"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "421da76b.670be8",
      "type": "output-distributer",
      "z": "c19ca393.e14b1",
      "name": "output-distributer",
      "device_id": "93e71ba7-fb56-5592-a5f6-d855203dd7ae",
      "device_name": "nmos-cpp_node_10-20-130-24:6131",
      "x": 620,
      "y": 260,
      "wires": [
        
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "6548d2cb.45bc1c",
      "type": "video-switcher",
      "z": "c19ca393.e14b1",
      "name": "video-switcher",
      "device_id": "93e71ba7-fb56-5592-a5f6-d855203dd7ae",
      "device_name": "nmos-cpp_node_10-20-130-24:6131",
      "x": 480,
      "y": 120,
      "wires": [
        [
          "421da76b.670be8"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "7cf8bc7e.204a84",
      "type": "audio-switcher",
      "z": "c19ca393.e14b1",
      "name": "audio-switcher",
      "device_id": "fe21abdf-706f-5c7b-adb8-2507e145e820",
      "device_name": "nmos-cpp_node_10-20-130-24:6121",
      "x": 440,
      "y": 360,
      "wires": [
        [
          "421da76b.670be8"
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
```

If I wanted to grab all the values of the **device id**, How is it possible?

Comment: If you have an array of objects, you can get the device_id of each element using the `.map` function: `var device_ids = arr.map(obj => obj.device_id);` `device_ids` ends up being an array of strings, each device_id

Comment: To turn a JSON string into a javascript object or array, use `JSON.parse`. If it's in a file and you're in node.js, you can also just `require` the file. eg `var records = require('./x.json');`

Comment: Yes,It is in a file and I read the file by this code :
fs.readFile("flow_demo_1.json", (err, data) => {
  if (err){
    console.log(err);
  }else {
  console.log(data.toString());
  }})                                                                                                                    and I just want to show in my browser keys=device_id and different values.

Comment: @TKoL Can you explain for me more how can I Json.parse and print my device_ids?

Comment: Well, if you have a string like `var str = "[{}]";` -- in other words a json string that represents an array -- you would do `var arr = JSON.parse(str);` and now the `arr` variable is an array that matches your json string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found my answer :

```
var fileContent = fs.readFileSync('flow_demo_1.json', 'utf8');
console.log(fileContent);
 const myObj = JSON.parse(fileContent)
 for (let obj of myObj) {
   if (obj.hasOwnProperty("device_id")) {
     console.log("device_id: " + obj.device_id);
   }
 }
```

Thanks every one.

Answer (score 0):

After you opened the file and get the data from it, iterate through array and check if object has property device_id `obj.hasOwnProperty("device_id")` , if it's present, print it:

```js
// edit after comment  ---------

async function getFileContent() {
  fs.readFile("flow_demo_1.json", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(data.toString());
      
      return data
    }
  })
}

// const fileContent =  await getFileContent();
// const myObj = JSON.parse(fileContent)

// ---------

const myObj = [{
    "id": "c19ca393.e14b1",
    "type": "tab",
    "label": "Flow 1",
    "disabled": false,
    "info": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "a15871bb.7c3b2",
    "type": "input-distributer",
    "z": "c19ca393.e14b1",
    "name": "input-distributer",
    "device_id": "93e71ba7-fb56-5592-a5f6-d855203dd7ae",
    "device_name": "nmos-cpp_node_10-20-130-24:6131",
    "audio_services": "{\"node-input-audio_services1\":\"c250498b-52ee-5162-b450-e15905912e8c\",\"audio_ip_1\":\"1.2.3.4\",\"audio_port_1\":\"1234\"}",
    "video_services": "{\"node-input-video_services1\":\"c250498b-52ee-5162-b450-e15905912e8c\",\"video_ip_1\":\"5.6.7.8\",\"video_port_1\":\"5678\"}",
    "x": 280,
    "y": 260,
    "wires": [
      [
        "6548d2cb.45bc1c"
      ],
      [
        "7cf8bc7e.204a84"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "421da76b.670be8",
    "type": "output-distributer",
    "z": "c19ca393.e14b1",
    "name": "output-distributer",
    "device_id": "93e71ba7-fb56-5592-a5f6-d855203dd7ae",
    "device_name": "nmos-cpp_node_10-20-130-24:6131",
    "audio_services": "{\"node-input-audio_services1\":\"7d010b65-b9d8-5561-a622-189b1c06d3f9\"}",
    "video_services": "{\"node-input-video_services1\":\"7d010b65-b9d8-5561-a622-189b1c06d3f9\"}",
    "x": 620,
    "y": 260,
    "wires": [

    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "6548d2cb.45bc1c",
    "type": "video-switcher",
    "z": "c19ca393.e14b1",
    "name": "video-switcher",
    "device_id": "93e71ba7-fb56-5592-a5f6-d855203dd7ae",
    "device_name": "nmos-cpp_node_10-20-130-24:6131",
    "video_senders": "{\"node-input-senders_services1\":\"c250498b-52ee-5162-b450-e15905912e8c\",\"senders_ip_1\":\"9.0.1.2\",\"senders_port_1\":\"9012\"}",
    "video_receivers": "{\"node-input-receivers_services1\":\"7d010b65-b9d8-5561-a622-189b1c06d3f9\"}",
    "x": 480,
    "y": 120,
    "wires": [
      [
        "421da76b.670be8"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "7cf8bc7e.204a84",
    "type": "audio-switcher",
    "z": "c19ca393.e14b1",
    "name": "audio-switcher",
    "device_id": "fe21abdf-706f-5c7b-adb8-2507e145e820",
    "device_name": "nmos-cpp_node_10-20-130-24:6121",
    "audio_senders": "{\"node-input-senders_services1\":\"7408e1be-a227-5d0a-a22b-294bcf22017c\",\"senders_ip_1\":\"0.0.0.0\",\"senders_port_1\":\"0000\"}",
    "audio_receivers": "{\"node-input-receivers_services1\":\"d08f3a50-41fc-5020-9c6c-175d91891aef\"}",
    "x": 440,
    "y": 360,
    "wires": [
      [
        "421da76b.670be8"
      ]
    ]
  }
]

for (let obj of myObj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty("device_id")) {
    console.log("device_id: " + obj.device_id)
  }
}
```

Comment: according to It is in a file and I read the file by this code : fs.readFile("flow_demo_1.json", (err, data) => { if (err){ console.log(err); }else { console.log(data.toString()); }})                                                                             and I just want to show in my browser keys=device_id and different values

Comment: `fs.readFile` isn't available in a browser. You're kinda mixing up server-side and client-side questions right here

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for getting device_id values

```
data.map(element => { // data refers to your array
  console.log(element['device_id']);
});
```

since in first object device_id is not there so it will print undefined and you can apply a check on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a check if `device_id` exists or not and the you can `.map` it.

Try this:

```js
let arr = [{"id":"c19ca393.e14b1","type":"tab","label":"Flow 1","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"a15871bb.7c3b2","type":"input-distributer","z":"c19ca393.e14b1","name":"input-distributer","device_id":"93e71ba7-fb56-5592-a5f6-d855203dd7ae","device_name":"nmos-cpp_node_10-20-130-24:6131","audio_services":"{\"node-input-audio_services1\":\"c250498b-52ee-5162-b450-e15905912e8c\",\"audio_ip_1\":\"1.2.3.4\",\"audio_port_1\":\"1234\"}","video_services":"{\"node-input-video_services1\":\"c250498b-52ee-5162-b450-e15905912e8c\",\"video_ip_1\":\"5.6.7.8\",\"video_port_1\":\"5678\"}","x":280,"y":260,"wires":[["6548d2cb.45bc1c"],["7cf8bc7e.204a84"]]},{"id":"421da76b.670be8","type":"output-distributer","z":"c19ca393.e14b1","name":"output-distributer","device_id":"93e71ba7-fb56-5592-a5f6-d855203dd7ae","device_name":"nmos-cpp_node_10-20-130-24:6131","audio_services":"{\"node-input-audio_services1\":\"7d010b65-b9d8-5561-a622-189b1c06d3f9\"}","video_services":"{\"node-input-video_services1\":\"7d010b65-b9d8-5561-a622-189b1c06d3f9\"}","x":620,"y":260,"wires":[]},{"id":"6548d2cb.45bc1c","type":"video-switcher","z":"c19ca393.e14b1","name":"video-switcher","device_id":"93e71ba7-fb56-5592-a5f6-d855203dd7ae","device_name":"nmos-cpp_node_10-20-130-24:6131","video_senders":"{\"node-input-senders_services1\":\"c250498b-52ee-5162-b450-e15905912e8c\",\"senders_ip_1\":\"9.0.1.2\",\"senders_port_1\":\"9012\"}","video_receivers":"{\"node-input-receivers_services1\":\"7d010b65-b9d8-5561-a622-189b1c06d3f9\"}","x":480,"y":120,"wires":[["421da76b.670be8"]]},{"id":"7cf8bc7e.204a84","type":"audio-switcher","z":"c19ca393.e14b1","name":"audio-switcher","device_id":"fe21abdf-706f-5c7b-adb8-2507e145e820","device_name":"nmos-cpp_node_10-20-130-24:6121","audio_senders":"{\"node-input-senders_services1\":\"7408e1be-a227-5d0a-a22b-294bcf22017c\",\"senders_ip_1\":\"0.0.0.0\",\"senders_port_1\":\"0000\"}","audio_receivers":"{\"node-input-receivers_services1\":\"d08f3a50-41fc-5020-9c6c-175d91891aef\"}","x":440,"y":360,"wires":[["421da76b.670be8"]]}]
let device_ids = arr.filter(o => o.device_id).map(obj => obj.device_id);
console.log(device_ids);
```

Comment: according to It is in a file and I read the file by this code : fs.readFile("flow_demo_1.json", (err, data) => { if (err){ console.log(err); }else { console.log(data.toString()); }})                                                                            and I just want to show in my browser keys=device_id and different values